# Selenium locaing elements_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium

Hi i am able to catch elements in network console with $x('//p[input]') but in python with selenium when using:

```
inputs = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[@input]")
```

i get nothing. What am i missing?

EDIT1:

I got this in console in brower:

[image]

in my code i have:

```
inputs = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[@input]")
print(len(inputs))
for i in inputs:
    print(i.text)
```

but i get 0 and nothing is listed, i am checking same url for sure.

EDIT2: url: http://fincoin.top/

Comment: Please add the html of element to locate.

Comment: please [edit] your question and provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

This will return list of elements so need to iterate over a list of elements

```
inputs = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[@input]")
for item in inputs :
    print item.text
```

To handle single element :

```
inputs = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@input]")
print inputs.text
```